# HTML footer is covering content and adding paddings and such doesnt change a thing

Tags: html, css

I'm using HTML and CSS and the issue I'm having is that after adding the footer and all its content, its size is covering content. I have tried adding on CSS padding, margins and such on the item footer but it keeps covering the item. The only page where it happens has a form in it, so that might be part of the issue.

I have also tried using breaks to separate the form and the footing but it doesn't work. What can I do?

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    Nom:
    <input type="text" name="nomUsuari" value="" />
  </p>

  <p>
    Adreça:
    <input type="text" name="adreçaUsuari" value="" />
  </p>

  <p>
    </label>Ciutat:
    <select id="adreça" name="ciutatUsuari">
      <option value="Girona">Girona</option>
      <option value="Barcelona">Barcelona</option>
      <option value="Campelles">Campelles</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="date">
        <p>Data de naixement:</p>
      </label>
    <input type="date" id="date" name="dataUsuari">
  </p>

  <legend>Gènere:</legend>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="title_1">
                      <input type="radio" id="title_1" name="title" value="Masculí">
                      Masculí
                    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="title_2">
                      <input type="radio" id="title_2" name="title" value="Femení" >
                      Femení
                    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="title_3">
                      <input type="radio" id="title_3" name="title" value="No binari
                    ">
                      No binari
                    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="title_4">
                      <input type="radio" id="title_4" name="title" value="No vull dir-ho">
                      No vull dir-ho
                    </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </fieldset>
  <p>

    <p>Correu electrònic:
      <input type="email" id="mail" name="mailUsuari">
    </p>

    <p>Password:
      <input type="password" id="pwd" name="passwordUsuari">
    </p>

    <p><input type="checkbox" value="condicions" name="condicions" id="condicionsUsuari" /> He llegit i accepto les condicions.

    </p>



    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />

</form>
<br />
<br />

<footer>
  <p><strong>Autor:</strong> Adrià Hernández Furtó <span class="footer-right"><a href="#">Instagram</a></span> </p>
  <HR>
  <p><strong>Telèfon:</strong> 666 666 666 <span class="footer-right"><a href="#">Facebook</a></span> </p>
  <HR>
  <p><strong>Correu:</strong> adrianer123@gmail.com <span class="footer-right"><a href="#">Steam</a></span> </p>
</footer>
```

I have tried changing the padding, the margin, i have tried making the #page have a margin at the bottom with the size of the footer.